# Filter and execute script from a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of html (divs and script) coming in an ajax response. Currently I can filter all of the script and execute it like so:

```
$(response).filter("script").each(function (i) {
        eval($(this).text());
});
```

What I need is a way to execute a script only from a specific DIV that comes in the response. How can I do that? JQuery seems strip away all the script if I do something like this:

```
$(response).filter("#specificDiv").filter("script").each(function (i) {
                            eval($(this).text());
                        });
```

which doesn't work, all script from 'specificDiv' is stripped away by jQuery.

JQuery is killing me with all the script stripping crap its doing.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that is because it is trying to find script tag in object of `#specificDiv` and not its child elements that have tagname as script. 
Filter selects subset of element from the selected element. which is `#specificDiv` here.

You need to modify filter function to:

```
 $(response).filter("#specificDiv script").each(function (i) {
                        eval($(this).text());
                    });
```

Comment: This seems to work, would you be able to comment on why this doesn't work with jQuery 1.8.3 ?

Comment: @AzureCloudDev: this has nothing to do with version. you have confused find with filter event.

Comment: Actually this doesn't seem to work, put an alert statement right before eval, it doesn't execute. But now my code is working because, before I was getting only Html, when I did $(text).filter('specificDiv').html(); to get new html for 'specificDiv' which was stripping all the script, now I get html & script, and script executes automatically! All I did is change jQuery version from 1.8.3 to 1.12.3.

Comment: OMG, I am not sure if this is the correct answer but you solved my problem LOL